# body height 100% with absolute positioned content doesn't work

Tags: css

To set body-height to 100% I use the following code:

```
html {height: 100%;}

body{
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;  
}
```

I thought this workaround works always, no matter what the content does, but when I use content, that is absolute positioned, the body seems to loose the 100%-height property.

You can see the example here:

1. Go to https://www.appfelsine.com/was-kostet-eine-App
2. Reduce the browser width as far as u can.
3. scroll down.
4. there is a white area at the bottom.

Position:fixed; would help for the white area, but then it is impossible to reach the button at the bottom.

position: fixed; and overflow-y:scroll; will result in a double scroll bar - doesn't look very nice.

Have you got an idea how to pull the body down until the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: fixed; overflow-y:auto;`  will prevent scrollbar showing when it is not getting overflow. It prevents double scrollbar issue

Comment: But can I scroll with a mobile device to the bottom of the green element? EDIT: Yes seems to work! Thanks You solving - I'm impressed :-)

Comment: You give` position:relative ; overflow:auto` in the outermost div so that the scroll will work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just put "background-color: #3ab252" on your ".question-inner" ?